# RavenDb session management for WCF and integration testing

Tags: wcf, session, integration-testing, ravendb

Put simply, I have a WCF service that manages apples. Apart from other functionality, it has two methods to add and remove apples from storage. I am writing an integration test to check if someone is getting advantage of the job and nicks apples. Raven DB in my WCF service has an audit role, it just records actions and apples. In the methods of WCF service there is some other processing: cleaning, validation, packaging etc.

My audit integration test can be expresses as

- Empty storage (RavenDB in-memory mode)
- Bob comes and puts 10 apple (open session, add, dispose session)
- Jake comes and takes 4 apples (open session, remove, dispose session)
- Check that 6 apples left

As these are two different people (two WCF calls) it make sense to use different instances of session. However, with Raven DB I get

**Exception**

> Apple is not associated with the session, cannot delete unknown entity
>   instance

If I now run similar integration test where two different people just *add* apples to the storage, the total storage content corresponds to truth. This is confusing bit: adding works across session, removing doesn't work. In [this post](https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/3fc7b131a6231124?pli=1) Ayende says session micro-managing is not the way to go, but it seems natural to me to use different sessions in my integration testing. Hope analogy with apples doesn't put you off.

**Question:** How do I use sessions in integration testing with RavenDB?

Sample code (from notepad)

```
public void Remove(Apple apple)
{
    using (var session = Store.OpenSession())
    {
        session.Delete(apple);
        session.SaveChanges();      
    }
}

public void Add(Apple apple)
{
    using (var session = Store.OpenSession())
    {
        session.Store(apple);
        session.SaveChanges();      
    }
}

...

var apples = new apples[10];
//init
MyRavenDB.Add(apples);
MyRavenDB.Remove(apples.Take(4)); //throws here
//verify
```

Comment: Don't have access to the code storage, but roughly this should show the issue with closing session and add-then-remove integration test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RavenDB, ["The session manages change tracking for all of the entities that it has either loaded or stored"](http://old.ravendb.net/documentation/client-api/unit-of-work).

I suspect the `Apple` reference you are passing to `Remove()` method, did not originate from RavenDB Document Store, hence the error.

Try this:

```
public void Remove(Apple apple)
{
    using (var session = Store.OpenSession())
    {
        var entity = session.Load<Apple>(apple.Id);

        session.Delete(entity);
        session.SaveChanges();      
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this line `var entity = session.Load<Apple>(apple.Id);` absolutely needed? I am trying to avoid loading up an entity if it still going to be removed.

Comment: Retrieving an entity using `Load<>(id)` method is a high performance operation. Unless you are talking to a remote RavenDB instance over a high-latency connection, or planning to delete hundreds of documents per second - don't worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing entities over the wire, and that is generally a big no-no.
Do it like this:

```
 public void Remove(string appleId)
```

That would give you much better sematnics.